# How to correctly add decimal integer to an address

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to add a decimal integer to an address. (I'm not very clear about address, I guess it works in hexadecimal) in the following way:

```
//node_t is a structure with an int and node_t* ptr, so i have the size 8
    int move = sizeof(node_t) + size; //here node_t is 8, size is 10
//so actually i want to move it by 18bytes.
    node_t* tmp = (current)+sizeof(node_t) / sizeof(node_t) + size/sizeof(int)
//current is the starting address, i try to get current moving positively with 18 bytes
```

But it turns out `tmp` is only 16 bytes greater than `current`.

I think the problem is that size is recognized as hexadecimal, how can I solve this?

Comment: *Why* would you wan't to do that?

Comment: Please provide a MCVE. You do not show any definition of your variable.

Comment: I have to simulate malloc() in simple way, and i trying to make a pointer pointing to header of next free space after assign the 10bytes(size).

Comment: You still do not show definitions of `a` and `current`

Comment: "the addition is done in hexadecimal" hexadecimal is only a represenation of numbers. Unless you print or scan numbers that has no meaning. The `sizeof` operator "returns" a value. Such a value does not have decimal or hexadecimal representation until you print it.

Answer (score 2):

This does not make much sense:

```
node_t* tmp = (current)+sizeof(node_t) / sizeof(node_t) + size/sizeof(int)
```

Pointer arithmetics works by adding a number of elements, not bytes.
You seem to try to take care about this by dividing the sizes but this cannot work.

From the expression I assume `current` is of type `node_t*`.
Adding `sizeof(node_t) / sizeof(node_t)` basically moves it behind current position. You could also just use `1` for this part.

Then you add `size/sizeof(int)`.
Here you assume a different size of elements: `int` instead of `node_t`.

You mention size of `node_t` is 8. How would you divide 10 by 8? `10/8` is 1 with integer division.
This means you always move by 2 elements, i.e. 16 bytes.

You could try this ugly hack instead:

```
node_t* tmp = (node_t *)(((char*)current) + sizeof(node_t) + size);
```

This can work if you do not have very strict alignment restrictions on your hardware.

Otherwise you need to round up to the next well aligned address.